# PHP session data lost after button redirect

Tags: php, session-variables

I am creating a website where users login and their data is stored in a PHP session.  On page 1 there is a button that links the user to a different page on the same site:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Go to different page" onclick="window.location.replace('page2.php');">
```

On page 2, I am unable to access the session data from page 1.

`var_dump($_SESSION);` returns "array(0) { }".

The session data is transferring when I redirect with php, but not with a button.
Is there a different way to redirect with a button, or am I missing something to transfer the session data?

## Update

### Page 1 relevant code

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 'NAME';
<input id="button" type="button" value="Go to different page" onclick="window.location.replace('page2.php');">
```

### Page 2 relevant code

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: Show us more code...

Answer (score 1):

you need to start the the session on each page.

```
session_start();
```

another Reason could be that you destory the session at the end of your first page.

Comment: `session_start();` is called before I try to access the session variables on the second page, it is not the first line of php code.  I don't call `session_destroy();` before the end of the first page, is there another way to destroy the session?

Comment: Yes, in the link location I only used the file name, and didn't include the full address to confirm the issue wasn't involving www or something else within the address.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Browser Developer Tools ? F12 and then search for the network tab. Look at the main request and view if the phpsession id changes when you visit the same page multiple times.